# Measuring extremely small inductance (pH) with transient pulse response

Tags: measurement, pulse, transient, test-equipment, inductance-measurement

I've made an inductor device. It has 2 terminals. It has inductance, resistance, and some parallel interwinding capacitance.

I am using a Keysight B1500a semiconductor probe station, which has transient current-voltage measurement capabilities.

It can measure down to the nanosecond and femtoamperes. However, I can only use 2 probes, one grounded, the other is a pulse source with a known rise time.

I want to measure the inductance of this device. I can figure out the resistance from the slope of a DC sweep. Let's disregard the capacitance for now as it complicates the math and the reactance is going to be largely positive (inductive).

I am trying to calculate the current response during the rising edge of the pulse. I assume the rising edge is a linear ramp of voltage.

Variables: V_pulse = pulse voltage, t_rise = time for the rising edge of the pulse, I(t) = Return current through the probe tip as a function of time, V(t) voltage applied to the device as a function of time.

On the probe station, I will be able to see the current at the end of the rising edge region which I have denoted I(trise).

The wolfram alpha solutions show the variables capital "T" which is t_rise. x= I(t_rise) or the current at the end of the rising edge region.

The W function is the "product log function" or Lambert W function, which I do not know how to evaluate or if it is even possible to measure inductance with this method.

[image: Math]

Comment: How do you know the response will be largely inductive and not capacitive? You'd only know that if you know what frequency is under discussion. And frankly, that depends on the entire system -- driver and load -- as a combined unit, doesn't it? Also, the *"I assume the rising edge is a linear ramp of voltage"* thing kind of bothers me as an axiom upon which all the rest is based. Especially as this is usually the case where a current source feeds a capacitance. Which would suggest the capacitance isn't to be ignored for these purposes. That's just a sanity check on my part. But I'm ignorant.

Comment: I've written more than a few answers here on LambertW and some of those provide detailed steps for applying it to find a closed solution. Just FYI. That said, I know nothing at all about the KeySight tool you are using. So again, I'm ignorant. Mostly, I just want you to write a little more. It would help me. It may help others, too.

Comment: You say you have a pulse generator with a known rise time but, isn't the rise time measured/calibrated with a known resistive load?  I'm not sure the rise time will be the same with an inductive load with different DC resistance.

Comment: An SMU is not the tool you want. Basically everything in the signal path will have more inductance than pH. You need very good **probes and high frequency equipment**. A good fast scope is more like it. Ignoring parasitics is absolutely flawed. There is no "pH-inductor". At this range, it is just a piece of "wire with some geometry" and even C and L become sort of meaningless and field solvers are more appropriate to judge the behavior. If you want to consider L and C, then you have to consider them together. If you have calibrated pH test standards, you can assemble a bridge configuration.